# Passing Null to ActionResult is causing an error yet logic seems correct

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

**Situation**

I am working on a project where a user fills in an application and has the ability to attach documents.
The document amount can vary so I will store then in a separate table and relate them by the application ID.

So far, I have the form with two tabs, one tab takes the details, the other tab is for the attaching of documents. 
The reason for this is, if a user clicks to add a document, I will prompt that they save the form first. That way, once the form is saved I will have the application ID that I need to relate the form to the attached documents.

**Problem**

The problem arises here

```
<div class="form-horizontal tab-pane" id="dvAttach">
         @Html.Action("documentList", "Application", new { id = Model.applicationID })
</div>
```

When the form loads, I intent to pass the applicationID to a method in the application controller that will list all the already attached documents based on that ID. However, on the create there is of course no applicationID so this is null. Instead of passing null to the `documentList` method, I am getting the error `Model.get returned null`.
PS `applicationID` is a string data type.

**Question**

How can I handle this situation so that I can load this page even if I dont have an application ID and null is returned.

**Update**

```
            @if (@Model.applicationID != null)
            {
                @Html.Action("documentList", "Application", new { id = Model.applicationID })
            }
```

Also gives me a null error

Answer (score 0):

Because when the page is getting loaded, there is no value in Model.applicationID. So better apply a check, whether Model is not null or the Model.applicationID value is not null.

Comment: I have added
                `@if (@Model.applicationID != null)
                {
                    @Html.Action("documentList", "Application", new { id = Model.applicationID })
                }` . But I am still getting a null error

Comment: It means there is nothing in Model. Bind your model properly.
Meanwhile apply check as below

@if (@Model != null)   {   ........ }